# Rules of tense agreement

Tags: grammar, tense-agreement

Do the tenses match in the following context?

- I **have done** as much as I **can/could** do to get selected for the job, still I **have failed.**

Should I use **can** or **could** there?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when **could** is used in the present tense, it is either used to ask for a request or to state a possibility. For example:

> 1. That could be Tom’s brother. He looks like Tom. (possibility)
> 2. Could I use your computer to email my boss? (request)

I think **can** would be a better choice for your sentence.

> I have done as much as I can do to get selected for the job, still I
>   have failed.

By the way, in order to improve your sentence, it's better to omit *do* after *can*. Because the meaning of the verb "do" can be easily understood from the previous part of your sentence.

> I have done as much as I can to get selected for the job, still I
>   have failed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you would like to emphasise.

- When discussing the general ability, I would use ***can***, which is the indicative form.

> I have done as much as I **can** do to get selected for the job, still I have failed.

means

> I have done as much as I am able to do, still I have not been
>   selected.

- When I want to emphasise the possibility, I would use ***could***, which is the past subjunctive form. This form is used when discussing possibility or irrealis.

> I have done as much as I **could** do to get selected for the job, still I have failed.

means

> I have done as much as possible to do to get the job, still I have not
>   been selected.

[This page](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/07/01/can-or-could/) has a good explanation for distinguishing between *can* and *could*. I hope this helps!